# find Location {{config('plugin.theme')}} in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, plugins, themes, config

How do I find the location of **{{config('plugin.theme')}}** in laravel?

I'm currently editing a Laravel that is fetching the home(index) page. but in the view folder there is a home.blade.php file in that file there is {{config('plugin.theme')}}.

where does the code lead? and how do I find the file?

```
   <!--  container content: START -->
   <div class="{{config('plugin.theme')}}"></div>
   <!--  container content: END -->
```

Comment: `/config + [dot notation]` in that case `/config/plugin.php:theme` _theme_ been the key in the file, [config](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-config)